# RokAjaxSearch RTL Issue (Result View)?

Tags: right-to-left, joomla-module, rokajaxsearch

RTL Languages, Joomla and RocketTheme Template.

RokAjaxSearch Module Issue

1. you type something and it doesn't narrow down the search as you type like when I first installed it. The list remains empty.
2. when you finish typing a word, the list comes empty and try: عزيز
   the drop-down list is empty although saying "Results" but nothing follows...
3. You start clicking on the arrows left and right for more results and sure enough you see the results.

Can someone explain this odd behavior and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this seems to fix it :

create a custom CSS file in your /CSS directory (the Rockettheme Template) or LESS folder.

**template-custom.less** or **rt_templatename-custom.css**

Add this code:

```
#roksearch_results .page {
float: none !important;
}
```